# eclipse run configurations can't find text file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to set up a program that will read a file as though from the command line with args[0]. I set up the run configuration in the "arguments" tab using my .txt file name under "program arguments" but it can't find it. I've tried importing the file from another source and adding the files to the project folder. I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. This is the code I'm using. I'm pretty new to all this so maybe it's something obvious I just don't know. I hope my question even makes sense.

```
Scanner input = null;
String fn = null;
try{
     fn = args[0];
     input = new Scanner(new File(fn));
  }
```

Comment: Can you show what you put in the arguments tab?

Comment: Please describe, where the text file, the eclipse project and the Java class are located.

Comment: In the arguments tab I put "test1.txt" in the "program arguments" without the quotes.

Comment: Is your workspace `C:\workspace`? Is your project location `C:\workspace\treehouse`? Is your source folder `C:\workspace\treehouse\src`? Is your java class in `C:\workspace\treehouse\src\Start.java`? Is your textfile `C:\workspace\treehouse\test1.txt`? Is your launch config's working directory `C:\workspace\treehouse`? Otherwise please post your file and folder locations.